# PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, gradle, hybrid-mobile-app

```
Launching lib\main.dart on IN2017 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
Note: C:\Users\Microsoft\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.13.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\Microsoft\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\device_info-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\deviceinfo\DeviceInfoPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Microsoft\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\Microsoft\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\geocoding_android-2.1.2\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geocoding\Geocoding.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Microsoft\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-4.4.0\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocation.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Microsoft\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\uni_links-0.5.1\android\src\main\java\name\avioli\unilinks\UniLinksPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Microsoft\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\stripe_android-9.5.0+1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\uimanager\DisplayMetricsHolder.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)
```

I am trying to run a flutter app but facing this mentioned issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hy guys!
my problem solved just by increasing Gradle Memory Allocation.

Just go to your_Project>android>gradle.properties and incresese your memory allocation.
My previous memory allocation was org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M, & i increased to
-----> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m

and boom, problem solved

Comment: please help i increased for org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G to org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8G but no resolution.